# SWIG typemap for two different target types?

Tags: c++, numpy, swig

I'm wrapping some C++ code with SWIG to Python, e.g. member functions like

```
Leek::update(const std::vector<double>& v);
```

In Python, I would like to use this function with both sequences and/or Numpy arrays. I understand that I could write my own `%typemap(in)` that checks and converts those types.

However, SWIG already offers a typemap for `std::vector`s to sequences, **is there a way to 'extend' the existing typemap with a typemap for Numpy arrays**, such that it checks and converts both types?

Until now, I've only been able to overwrite the built-in typemap, which is undesirable.

Comment: Using the `numpy.i` provided with NumPy, you can pass arrays instead of Numpy arrays, i.e. `SomeFunction([0.0,1.0,2.0])` as well as `SomeFunction(np.array([0.1,1.0,2.0],dtype=np.float32))` works when you use of the typemaps provided

Comment: Thanks for the hint!